# Why won't CSS in Github Pages not show up?

Tags: html, css, github, hyperlink

I am working on a Github pages site, a web game of sorts. It's called World, and it's on "worldfantasy.github.io". The game is being developed, and I'm using CSS to style the page. But Github won't recongize the file as CSS. The file is called 'main.css', and here's the code I use to link it to the 'index.html' file:

```
<head>
  <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" href="main.js" language="Javascript></script>
  <title>World</title>
</head>
```

But when I visit the site, the CSS backgrounds and styling don't work. It's a plain html website. So my question is...How do I get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Open developer tools, right-click on the refresh button and choose clear cache. See if that solves the problem.

Comment: Seems to be loading fine here.

Comment: It looks fine to me too.